# How can I get and activate all windows 10 child features of a feature using powershell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I know I can get a Windows 10 optional feature status with

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "NetFx4-AdvSrvs"
```

My question is, how can I get all the "child" features of that feature?

[image: Example in admin tools]

For completness, this is the result of the command above:

```
FeatureName      : NetFx4-AdvSrvs
DisplayName      : .NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services
Description      : .NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
                   ServerComponent\Description : .NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services
                   ServerComponent\DisplayName : .NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services
                   ServerComponent\Id : 450
                   ServerComponent\Type : Feature
                   ServerComponent\UniqueName : NET-Framework-45-AdvSrvs
                   ServerComponent\Deploys\Update\Name : NetFx4-AdvSrvs
                   ServerComponent\Version\Major : 4
                   ServerComponent\Version\Minor : 5
```

As a followup example on Windows Server I can do this to activate a feature and all sub features:

```
import-module servermanager
Add-WindowsFeature NetFx3 -IncludeAllSubFeature
```

**So to further refine the question, is there a way to do something similar on Windows 10?**

Comment: According to [Get-WindowsOptionalFeature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/get-windowsoptionalfeature?view=win10-ps) you will use the "*PackageName*" parameter to get all of the features in the package.

Comment: Check out [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&view=win10-ps) `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "NetFx4-AdvSrvs" -All`.

Comment: The `-All` gets the parent of the feature enabled (default)  values but not the children

Comment: I also tried `| Get-ChildItem` but no dice there

Comment: Try using something like "`netfx4extended-aspnet45`" instead then maybe. Otherwise, look into [Install-WindowsFeature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanager/install-windowsfeature?view=winserver2012r2-ps) potentially and the `-IncludeAllSubFeature`. Otherwise you might have to consider [dism](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism) commands instead with Windows 10. Those are some more ideas for you though.

Comment: I kind of wanted to stay away from RSAT if possible re: https://serverfault.com/q/713187/37301

Comment: In that case, consider the `dism` method I suggested or see if you can be explicit with the sub-feature names perhaps. I wasn't sure if the `netfx4extended-~` would provide further implicitness of child or sub-features but perhaps a Google search or so away from finding. You could always use the `dism` method if you're limited with your possibilities though I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The IncludeAllSubFeature switch is still present in windows 10 for use:[image]

This should do what you neeed it to